# Encryptions handled in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

Hi I want to know how encryption is handled in react native mobile Apps. What is done to encrypt data when using POST to send data to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a request from a react-native application you will most likely use the `fetch` API. Since `fetch` API supports `https` requests your requests will be encrypted the same way they would be from a browser. That is if you use `https` and not `http`.

**UPDATE:**

I am gonna answer your question here since it is too much for a comment.

Stopping someone from sending requests to your server is not possible since the url is public. It is like taking the url from a site (e.g. Google) and sending requests.

Now if they can do something malicious just by getting a hold of the url and spamming, this is a vulnerability of the server and you have to handle it on the server(you will still receive the request), you can find a lot of things about how to secure your server on google.

Comment: Thank you, also what would I need to do to make sure only the mobile client and server can only communicate with each other? an example, if someone gets a hold of my api url they would not be able to make requests or do anything malicious since the url will be stored client side